# What is the function of the '-n option' in sed?

Tags: sed

Can anyone give me an example to showcase the usage of the `-n` option? The way the document explained it was too vague for me.

Comment: What happened when you tried using it?

Answer (score 2):

Toggles if the line is printed even if no match.

Given these lines:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {a..c}{0..1} 
a0
a1
b0
b1
c0
c1
```

With `-n` only prints the lines with a '1' match:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {a..c}{0..1} | sed -n '/1/p;'
a1
b1
c1
```

Without `-n` every line is printed and the lines with '1' match are printed a second time because of the `p` command:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {a..c}{0..1} | sed  '/1/p;'
a0
a1
a1
b0
b1
b1
c0
c1
c1
```

Easily available with `man sed`:

```
 -n      By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard output
         after all of the commands have been applied to it.  The -n option
         suppresses this behavior.
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-n` option when you're using `sed` as a filter and are mainly eliminating material, so you don't want input lines printed by default. In the absence of `-n`, at the end of each edit cycle, the 'line' in the pattern space is printed by default.  For example:

```
sed -n -e '/something/ s/another-thing/dohicky/p' some-file
```

This looks for lines containing 'something', and effectively ignores all other lines.  On the lines that match 'something', the string 'another-thing' is replaced by 'dohicky' and the resulting line is printed.

A slightly more realistic example: change the shell of users of `csh` to `tcsh`:

```
sed -n -e '/\bin\csh/ s%/bin/csh%/bin/tcsh%p' /etc/passwd
```

This shows you only the lines that will be changed.  Then, if you decide it is correct, you can use:

```
sed -i .bak -e '/\bin\csh/ s%/bin/csh%/bin/tcsh%' /etc/passwd
```

to make the changes permanent.  Still not a good example (you need to lock the password file so it is not modified by other programs while you're editing it, and so on and so forth), but it looks more realistic.